# show text on icon selection how many icons have selected

Tags: javascript

i have a js code that limit the icons selection up to 14 and i want to display the number of icons that i have selected separately show the text that i have selected on the left side and right side
i want to update  '12 Monte' the number of icons selected.
and i want also to update the right side which is '2 minte'

```js
const icons = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-baby");
for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
  icons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let ctn = document.getElementsByClassName("text-primary").length;
    if (ctn <= 14 && !this.classList.contains("text-primary")) {
      this.classList.add("text-primary");
    } else if (this.classList.contains("text-primary")) {
      this.classList.remove("text-primary");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.6/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <td style="border:none;"> </td>
    <td style="border:none;">
      <p>Maxi</p>
      <p>Geschlect</p>
      <form>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <select class="mdl-textfield__input" id="octane" name="octane">
            <option value="">weiiblich</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td style="border:none;">
      <p>Partnerin</p>
      <p>Geschlect</p>
      <form>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <select class="mdl-textfield__input" id="octane" name="octane">
            <option>weiiblich</option>
            <option value="" selected>mannlich</option>
            <option>*</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <select class="mdl-textfield__input" id="octane1" name="octane1">
              <option id="march2019" value="march2019">March 2019</option>
              <option id="april2019" value="april2019">April 2019</option>
              <option id="may2019" value="may2019">May 2019</option>
              <option id="june2019" value="june2019">June 2019</option>
              <option id="july2019" value="july2019">July 2019</option>
              <option id="auguest2019" value="auguest2019">Auguest 2019</option>
              <option id="september2019" value="september2019">September 2019</option>
              <option id="october2019" value="october2019">October 2019</option>
              <option id="november2019" value="november2019">November 2019</option>
              <option id="december2019" value="december2019">December 2019</option>
              <option id="january2020" value="january2020">January 2020</option>
              <option id="febuary2020" value="feburary2020">Feburary 2020</option>
              <option id="march2020" value="march2020">March 2020</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <form>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para1">April 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para2">May 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para3">June 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para4">July 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para5">Augest 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para6">Setember 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para7">October 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para8">November 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para9">December 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para10">January 2020</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para11">Fabruary 2020</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para12">March 2020</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p id="para13">April 2020</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>12 monte</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>2 monte</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh counter variables values every time you click in a button, with the amount selected and the amount left.
It's possible to add a id attribute to the "td" elements, get then with "getElementById" and refresh it's inner html content with the new counter values.